# jquery .not() not working

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

```
$(document).not('.myform-links').click(function (event) {                    
     $('.myform-links').toggle();
});
```

At some point, an element is clicked which toggles the `.myform-links div` element to show.

This element is using the [CenterIt](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CenterIt) jquery plugin to make the `div` element float centered on top of the page.

I'm trying to use the above code to detect a click that is anywhere that is not in the element that is floating so that it may toggle back to its hidden status.

EDIT:

```
$(document).not('.myform-links').click(function() {                    
    $('.myform-links').toggle();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myform-links').CenterIt();
    $('.myform-links').hide();
});
$('#toggle').live('click',function() {
    $('.myform-links').toggle();
});
```

This is all of the code I am using to manipulate the element and the first posted code is the code that is not working.

based on the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) documentation, I see no reason why this should not work.  It would appear that either the element is changed by the CenterIt() or the object model that is created does not have the .myform-links in it.

Comment: When do you run the code fragment above?   Once at load or everytime you toggle the myform-links class and make a div-element float

Comment: The code above is supposed to be triggered by a click anywhere on the document that is not the .myform-links div element

Comment: Please get in the habit of describing what is wrong. "Not working" is not an error description.

Comment: Wes -- we get you want to run the function on each click, but where do  you actual run the setup function?  Does it run once, or everytime?  Describe what you think is wrong with it.   The code and the description is too little to help you.

Comment: I apologize.  I think in trying to show how simple the issue is I have left out information that I did not think was important as to not confuse people.  I have edited the OP to show exactly what is going on as it is in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax isn't quite right. You should to use the not(); function within a selector, i.e.

```
$(document:not('.myform-links')).click(function() {                    
     $('.myform-links').toggle();
});
```

And unless you're going to reuse the event you don't need to state it in the function.

Comment: I have to apologize, I do not know javascript or jquery all that well and am always looking for somebody to help with that area.  I do not quite understand what function you are talking about.  The way I have it coded is the only way I know how to make it work.  What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Ah yeap - I just read over his issue again - and I've helped him do the opposite of what he wants

Comment: With the syntax that you are using I am showing a syntax error.  Additionally it makes all of the javascript fail.

Comment: Could you link to the page you're having issues?

Comment: This is a syntax error, grant. I think you meant `$(':not(.myform-links)'), $(document)).click...`, or `$(document).find(':not(.myform-links)').click...`, or similar.

Comment: Still syntax, unexpected token :

Comment: `$("document:not('.myform-links')")` Makes it so that it hides it when anything is clicked and ignores the .not() but gets rid of the syntax problem

Answer (score -1):

This code will not work because the click event is bubble till document and it will trigger the event. Try the below code

```
$(document).click(function (event) {  
     $('.myform-links').toggle();
});

$('.myform-links').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
$('#toggle').live('click',function(e) {
    $('.myform-links').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: No dice, same results.  The form continues to float above the rest of the document.  Now mind you I can click the original toggle element to remove it but i would like a click anywhere to do it as well.

Comment: You click anywhere in the document the links will be toggled. But if you click in "myforms-links" container it will not hide. This is what the above code will do.

Comment: How can you down vote? This is what OP is trying to achieve as per the question.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work. I have edited the the OP as to show all the code involved.

Comment: by the way, this makes it so that no matter where I click the item is toggled.  Even if I made it so only the toggle element triggered the toggle, it would still hide and show no matter where i click

Comment: @Wes - Please check I have edited my answer based on your edit. Try it and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It still toggles no matter where I click.  I am starting to think that what I thought would be a simple question was not so simple.  Perhaps I just dont understand enough about how selectors work.

Comment: `$(document).click(function (event) {  
         $('.myform-links').toggle();
    });`  Is where the issue is.  This should make it so that if you click any where execpt the .myform-links element that it should fire the toggle event

Comment: If you click on .myform-links the document.click in not triggered. It is taken care by e.stopPropagation in $('.myform-links').click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

Comment: If you click anywhere else then $(document).click(function (event) { $('.myform-links').toggle(); }); will be triggered which will toggle the links.